# How can I use the AVAudioSEssion in a swift package when the package could be used by Macos?

Tags: swift, macos, avaudiosession, swift-package-manager

```swift
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

@available(iOS 14, *)
extension AVAudioSession {

    class func set(category: AVAudioSession.Category = .playback) {
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(category)
        } catch {
            print("Audio session failed", error)
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Even when I use the `@available(` attribution it doesn't work. How can I use the AVAudioSEssion in a swift package when the package could be used by Macos?

Comment: `#if os(iOS)` or `#if !os(macOS)`

Comment: I will select it if you add it as an answer.  Thank you @Cyberbeni

Comment: hmm... the error came back without any changes.